# Set Vista file view to "details" property listing?

Tags: windows-vista, windows-explorer

Is it possible to do a global setting so that whenever I open an explorer folder in Vista in details view, I see the file extension and date the file was created?

Answer (score 1):

In an explorer window, **set the view to detail view** then navigate to **Tools -> Folder Options**, and:

- Uncheck "hide extensions for known filetypes"
- Click "Apply to All Folders"
- Apply & OK

[image]

Extensions should always be visible and default view will be detailed view.